# GlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask not functioning in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift2, nsevent

I created a simple command line app, all it does is print the current program and log keydownevents.

My keydown events is done like this:

```
let eventObserver = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDownMask) { 
  (event) -> Void in
    Swift.print("Event is \(event)")
}
```

I run it on Xcode, and it prints the application (at runtime) but no key events outside of the application.

My thoughts, could have something to do with sandboxing in Xcode - it simply isn't able to register global events, but the application is sometimes not Xcode and that works.
So, am I missunderstanding how eventHandler works? Or is there something wrong with my code.

I'm using Xcode 7 beta 5 and swift 2, but I'm guessing this is generalizable to swift 1.2

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:) you can only monitor global events if your application is trusted for accessibility events. could that be your issue?

Comment: Yes is not trusted! How would I go about changing that? It's a command line app and seems to have less options in the .xcodeproj file

Comment: @UnholySheep I've not made it trusted, but still nothing is printing. Any thoughts?